# Assigning the lower value to its key in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to make a dictionary from two lists which are related to each other based on their indexes, i.e. list1[i] -> list2[i]. It can be seen that the keys list contains duplicate values and I would like the lower value to be assigned to its corresponding key (e.g. values 1 and 9 for key 9 but I want the lower value)

```
keys = [9, 9, 8, 10, 10]
values = [1, 9, 1, 6, 1]
dict = {10:1, 9:1, 8:1} #end result
```

Note: I am using a dictionary as I am trying to take advantage of the fact that there cannot be duplicate keys - if there are suggestions for a better data structure, please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through your keys and values, and use `min` to assign the minimum value:

```
>>> keys = [9, 9, 8, 10, 10]
>>> values = [1, 9, 1, 6, 1]
>>> inf = float('inf')
>>> result = {}
>>> for k,v in zip(keys, values):
...     result[k] = min(v, result.get(k, inf))
...
>>> result
{9: 1, 8: 1, 10: 1}
```

Note, I'm taking advantage of the fact that `float(inf)` is *always* greater than some other number.

Or alternatively, just check for the value in the dictionary:

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for k, v in zip(keys, values):
...     if k in result:
...         result[k] = min(v, result[k])
...     else:
...         result[k] = v
...
>>> result
{9: 1, 8: 1, 10: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = [9, 9, 8, 10, 10]
values = [1, 9, 1, 6, 1]

# By sorting in descending order based upon values, 
# smaller later values overwrite larger earlier 
# values in dictionary comprehension
result = dict(sorted(zip(keys, values), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True))

print(result) # => {9: 1, 10: 1, 8: 1}
```